# Code returns command not found, but I'm not sure where I'm putting a command in

Tags: python

I am trying to capture my keystrokes and return them back to myself. When I run the code I expect to get back what I whichever keys I pressed while the code was running in that order. I don't have an issue there, everything returns fine. But then after the code is ran it returns '-Bash: (*myinput*): command not found

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keyboard

keys = []

def keys_in():
    try:
        while True:
                recorded = keyboard.read_key(suppress=True)
                keys.append(recorded)
                if recorded == 'enter':
                        print(sorted(set(keys),key=keys.index))
                        break

                keys.append(recorded)


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('done')
        quit()
 keys_in()
```

When I put 1234 in I get :['1', '2', '3', '4', 'enter']

$ 1234
-bash: 1234: command not found
And I'm not sure why it's trying to run my input afterword. Help?

Comment: This seems to be a clarified version of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53184754/1222951), so please delete that one.

Comment: I'm confused. Not many do it, but i think it could be a reallygood idea to give a brief overview of what you're actually tryingto do -- as in you end goal as a final project. It helps put everything in context and may help other guide you in a different (more optimal?) direction.I tried it for 20 and I just got confused at what you were trying to do. Feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Are you running this code from command line?

Comment: Do you need to catch each key as it is entered?  If you can just get the whole line in one go you can use 'input'

Comment: not what hes trying to do. The shell is executing the program and then is executing by "quit." when it receives stdin after that, as we all know, you get that command. Just mash some letters on your command prompt and you will see that. Remember, "quit" means: "I don't care what's next or what you want to do, this code is no longer executing, you told me to do so" Gotta love it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard     


s = set()    

def keys_in():
    recorded = keyboard.read_key(suppress=True)
        while recorded != "enter":
            s.add(recorded)
            print(list(s))
keys_in()
```

Try this out. Sets are already sorted. you dont need to add. Does this do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `keyboard` module but it appears that, while it does indeed pass the input to the python program, it does it in such a way that the shell gets the input when the python program exits, as if it had been entered on the command line.  Here are two options (which do not require installing the keyboard module):

Using sys.stdin.read

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

keys = []

def keys_in():
    try:
        while True:
                recorded = sys.stdin.read(1)

                keys.append(recorded)
                if recorded == '\n':
                        print(sorted(set(keys),key=keys.index))
                        break

                keys.append(recorded)


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('done')
        quit()
keys_in()
```

Using 'input'

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

keys = []

def keys_in():
    try:
        input_string = input('')
        for recorded in input_string:
                keys.append(recorded)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('done')
        quit()

    print(sorted(set(keys),key=keys.index))

keys_in()
```

Comment: Note that the first one includes the carriage return in 'keys', and the second does not. This can be fine-tuned depending on your needs.